# From a starting ActiveCell, how to randomly generate surrounding cells and further randomly generate from a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, random, cells

I am trying to get cells to visually represent a randomized set of numbers, that are able to expand outward based on a while loop (lets start small with just making this a 5x5 grid though and I can update as necessary).

EXAMPLE: if my center active cell is a number =randbetween(1,10) where the answers of 1-9 place more random numbers from 1-10 in the adjacent cells surrounding it. However, if the value is **"10"** I want the cells around this cell that **haven't** been filled in to have the formula next to them being =randbetween(11,20). I can't seem to figure out how to do this without having it overwrite everything and just being one set of numbers.

The answer from this can also be used for non-randomized usage (like if someone wanted to show how if there was a chair in one space then they know that either a table or a trashcan etc would be in the space next to it)

Thanks for taking a look at my question!

It should look like this when it is done:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems you have misunderstood what this site is all about. Please take a moment to read [ask], and browse the [help/on-topic] for all you need to know before asking here.

Comment: Uh oh, I may have missed something, thanks for letting me know something is wrong as this is my first post to the site. I read the how to ask and I'm wondering if I broke the rule: your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Comment: Or is this the wrong stack exchange site (I meant to put it in excel VBA sub-site). Or it is possible that I made the question too open ended in how it can be solved? Or was this asked already and I just searched for it incorrectly? I appreciate you taking the time to help me understand how to improve my interactions with this website, and apologize for my lack of experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this for a while, I  figured I would share what ended up working for me as atonement:

```
    Dim k As Single 'Total Move Count
    Dim x As Single 'Starting point of spiral
    Dim bool As Boolean 'Boolean for direction change
    bool = True 'starts boolean as true
    k = 1 'starts count at 1
    x = 0 ' starts position as 0
    Dim i As Single
    i = 1
    Dim j As Single
    j = 1

    Do While x <= 10

        For n = 0 To k
            If bool = True Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "=randbetween(0,100)"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'Move Right
            i = i + 1
            Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "=randbetween(100,200)"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select 'Move Left
            i = i - 1
            End If
        Next n

         For n = 0 To k
            If bool = True Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "=randbetween(200,300)"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Down
            i = i + 1
            ActiveCell.Value = "=randbetween(300,400)"
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select 'Up
            i = i - 1
            End If
         Next n

    k = k + 1
    bool = Not bool
    'MsgBox bool
    x = x + 1
    Loop
```

I hope this helps someone else!